# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation in Windows 10 requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-10, .net-3.5, database-installation

I am trying to install **SQL Server 2008 R2 in Windows 10 Pro** edition. Windows 10 Pro is installed in 64 bit. But the installation fails. It requires **.Net Framework 3.5 SP 1**. So I made sure that .NET Framework 3.5 is installed with Windows 10 Add/Remove features from the control panel. Despite the installation of .NET Framework 3.5 from Add/Remove features of Windows 10, SQL Server 2008 R2 still requires the same framework. Now I am confused and don't know what to do. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Depending on the 2008 flavour that you are using, it might be [FW 2.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2027770/understanding-the-net-framework-requirements-for-various-versions-of-s#win2008r2) that is required. However the main problem is that 2008 is not supported on Windows 10.

Comment: In addition to not being supported on Windows 10, SQL Server 2008 R2 support ends in less than 2 weeks. If you must run it and on Windows 10, consider installing it on a Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V VM. That's what I do.